# How do I make Visual Studio Code auto-fix line indentation when I hit DEL?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Suppose I have the following code, where `|` represents the current position of my caret and `•` represents a single space character:

```
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
••|
••let test = 100;
}
```

When I hit Delete on my keyboard, I get this:

```
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
••|••let test = 100;
}
```

The problem: The two spaces before `let` were not stripped. What I expect is:

```
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
••|let test = 100;
}
```

I'd like VS Code to automatically format the line brought up to the current line when Delete ends up removing a newline character. Jetbrains Rider, for example, offers this kind of functionality.

I feel like there might be other scenarios similar to this where one line moves to another, and auto formatting would be ideal. So I hope there's a way to handle all of them within reason.

At the very least, having this kind of formatting for Typescript files would be acceptable, but ideally I would love for this to be available for any files that I edit.

Answer (score -1):

Simply go to keyboard shortcuts and search for `cut`, it is bind to `Shift + DEL` by default and change it to *DEL*.

Comment: This is not an automatic solution.

Comment: Then I will tell microsoft to create a specific method for you.